# install PHP-MySQL library on CentOS 6.8

Tags: centos

I want to install PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.0.95 on CentOS 6.8.

First, I install PHP 5.3.

```
yum install php-5.3.3
```

Second, I install MySQL 5.0.95.

```
rpm -Uvh MySQL-client-5.0.95-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh MySQL-server-5.0.95-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh MySQL-shared-5.0.95-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm
```

Now I want to install PHP-MySQL library. How should I install it?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to what you have done to install php-5.3

Just run:

```
yum install php-mysql
```